# Number Probability over significant time (roulette/lotto/keno and similar)

Tags: probability

Please excuse the lack of correct mathematical terminology.

When thinking about number probability in relation to games like roulette, or even lotto/lottery draws, keno, ...

Provided that there is no bias in the physical machine (for example, all lotto balls are equally weighted), my understanding is that every number should have the exact same probability of being drawn.

That said, lots of these machines also like to tell you things like "these are the least drawn numbers" and "the last 4 numbers drawn are...". I understand that these sort of statistics should be irrelevant. In lotto, for example, none of the lotto balls 'know' what the previous drawn numbers were, and they still have equal probability to be drawn next.

However, isn't there a Theory of Probability or Theory of Even Distribution that can come in to play here. Something like, given a long-enough time, and no bias, all numbers should eventually be drawn in equal amounts. If this is the case, shouldn't it actually be slightly more favorable to choose numbers from the "lest drawn" pile, as these numbers should be slightly more likely to be drawn given significant time?

Are these 2 things correct? They appear to be mutually exclusive - ie either all numbers will always be equally likely to appear, or they're skewed slightly over long-enough time - you can't have both. Could someone please explain to me the flaw in my logic/understanding. Is it simply that the "given significant time" is so phenomenally large that it is pretty-much irrelevant?

Comment: There's the law of large numbers. It says that the frequency of all numbers should limit to about equal, if the process is fair. This doesn't make the next draw unfair, in the sense that one ball is preferenced over another. It simply observes that after enormous numbers of fair trials, any local aberrant behaviour will be dwarfed by the sheer number of trials. So, the next number won't be more likely to be something different, but you're unlikely to see the same behaviour over and over again, indefinitely into the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you flip a fair coin 100 times, and it comes up heads 55 times. That's 55% heads, and it's 5 heads more than expected.

Now keep flipping until you reach 1000 times. The coin has no memory; it doesn't know that it has to make up for those excess heads; so the most likely outcome after 1000 tosses is that you'll still have an excess of 5 heads. But that means 505 heads, which is only 50.5%

So, the percentage of heads is approaching 50%, but the excess of heads could be there to stay.